# Securing REST interfaces

Tags: security, http, rest, interface, oauth-2.0

What are the general steps in securing REST interfaces, when exposed as JSON over HTTP?

Here is what I am thinking (will be using OAuth2 for authentication):

- Sanitise inputs on both client and server side
- Force HTTPS on secure endpoints
- Provide CSRF protection (use `state` param in OAuth2 flow)
- Put a queue+cache—e.g.: Redis—between endpoints and client, and between endpoints and backend components; to help deal with possible DDoS [and for general performance]
- Ensure firewall and other such mechanisms are in place (web-server security)

How else would you propose I *batten down the hatches* before taking this system live?

Answer (score 0):

My points :

1- Use https throughout, not just on secure endpoints. This will prevent "man in the middle" type issues.
2- AFAIK, you will need CSRF protection only if you are implementing the "authorization code" grant type. 
3- For minor DDoS attacks, use something like apache's mod_evasive to prevent this at the web server layer itself instead of going to the application layer. For major ones (you can rent a botnet of hundreds/thousands of computers for a few hundred dollars these days), you will need a costly solution by Akamai or something similar.